# Unity - Top Down Perspective Camera to Orthographic size

Tags: unity, camera

I have a perspective camera with an fov of 60.
It looks at an object from top view with a rotation(90, 0, 0) and position (0, 50, 0)

The user has the option to change the camera to orthographic view to get a 2D view without any depth from top

Now how can i calculate the orthographic size so the view looks same as that in the perspective view(just not having the depth)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  size
--------
 \     | d
  \    | i
   \  f| s
    \ o| t
     \v|
      \|
```

`size / distance = tan(fov)` using SOHCAHTOA

`size = distance * tan(fov)`

So the orthographic size should be set to `distance * Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad(fov))` where `distance` is how far away the camera is from the object it's viewing (in your case, I believe `50`).

If you know that you won't change the FOV, and/or you know the distance, you can pre-calculate it. For `60 degs` and `50 units` the orthographic size will be `86.6025403784`.